# List of lengths from list of strings using map, filter, or fold-right

Tags: scheme, racket, mit-scheme

> You are given a list of strings.
>
> Generate a procedure such that applying this procedure to such a list
>   would result in a list of the lengths of each of the strings in the
>   input.
>
> **Use `map`, `filter`, or `fold-right`.**
>
> ```
> (lengths (list "This" "is" "not" "fun")) => (4 2 3 3)
>
> (define lengths (lambda (lst) your_code_here))
> ```

I got stuck in the following code and I do not understand how can I use `filter`.

```
(define lengths
  (lambda (lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        nil
        (fold-right list (string-length (car lst)) (cdr lst)))))
```

Comment: "Use map, [**or**] filter, **or** fold-right."  You don't need to use _all_ of these.  `map` will be enough.  You don't have to use `filter` (or `fold-right`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a work for [`map`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29), you just have to pass the right procedure as a parameter:

```
(define (lengths lst)
  (map string-length lst))
```

As you should know, `map` applies a procedure to each of the elements in the input list, returning a new list collecting the results. If we're interested in building a list with the lengths of strings, then we call `string-length` on each element. The procedure pretty much writes itself!

A word of advice: read the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html) of the procedures you're being asked to use, the code you're writing is overly complicated. This was clearly *not* a job for `filter`, although `fold-right` could have been used, too. Just remember: let the higher-order procedure take care of the iteration, you don't have to do it explicitly:

```
(define (lengths lst)
  (fold-right (lambda (x a) 
                (cons (string-length x) a))
              '()
              lst))
```

Comment: This is the right answer, but I don't understand what x and a stands for? I mean what are they representing?

Comment: @cecemelly `fold-right` receives as its first parameter a _function_. That function in turn, receives two parameters. The one I called `x` is the current element in the list we're traversing, and the one called `a` is the answer accumulated so far, and that's what we return at the end; in the code above it starts with an initial value of `'()` (we passed this as the second parameter to `fold-right`). All this is in the documentation, I urge you to read it first

Comment: I have already read the documentation but maybe I need to practice English. Your explantion is really simple and clear, thank you.

Comment: @cecemelly always my pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like homework so I'll only give you pointers:

`map` takes a procedure and applies to to every element of a list. Thus

```
(define (is-strings lst)
    (map string? lst))

(is-strings '("hello" 5 sym "89")) ; (#t #f #f #t)

(define (add-two lst)
    (map (lambda (x) (+ x 2)) lst))

(add-two '(3 4 5 6)) ; ==> (5 6 7 8)
```

`filter` takes procedure that acts as a predicate. If #f the element is omitted, else the element is in the resulting list.

```
(define (filter-strings lst)
    (filter string? lst))

(filter-strings '(3 5 "hey" test "you")) ; ==> ("hey" "you")
```

`fold-right` takes an initial value and a procedure that takes an accumulated value and a element and supposed to generate a new value:

```
(fold-right + 0 '(3 4 5 6))      ; ==> 18, since its (+ 3 (+ 4 (+ 5 (+ 6 0))))
(fold-right cons '() '(a b c d)) ; ==> (a b c d) since its (cons a (cons b (cons c (cons d '()))))
(fold-right - 0 '(1 2 3))        ; ==> -2 since its (- 1 (- 2 (- 3 0)))
(fold-right (lambda (e1 acc) (if (<= acc e1) acc e1)) +Inf.0 '(7 6 2 3)) ; ==> 2
```

`fold-right` has a left handed brother that is iterative and faster, though for list processing it would reverse the order after processing..

```
(fold-left (lambda (acc e1) (cons e1 acc)) '() '(1 2 3 4)) ; ==> (4 3 2 1)
```